# When talking about many things that all have one thing, do you use the plural or singular?

Tags: grammaticality, grammatical-number

If you have something like:

> Get the *name(s)* of all users.

Should *name* be singular or plural?

The way I see it, each user has only one name, so it could be singular, but you will be getting many names, one for each users, so it could also be plural. Anyone know what is the proper way?

Comment: Also, is it "each user" or "each users"?

Comment: "Get the name for all the users" would make sense, as would "Get the name of each of the users". "Get the names of all users" means "Get all the names that can be attributed to the users"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When used with the word *all*, the plural is preferred in order to match the plural *users*:

> Get the names of all users.

With the word *each*, the singular is preferred in order to match the singular *user*:

> Get the name of each user.

However, even in this latter case, some people would accept or prefer *names*. There is not a hard-and-fast rule in this case, though in general English speakers err on the side of using the plural.

Comment: "Get the name of each user.

However, even in this latter case, some people would accept or prefer names. There is not a hard-and-fast rule in this case, though in general English speakers err on the side of using the plural."     Strongly disagree; they would err on the side of using the singular and that would be the only correct choice.  Most people would only use plural if they had multiple names.

Answer (score 1):

You want names, so names is correct.  Consider 'age' instead of 'name'.  You may ask for the *age* of all kids in one grade at school, but you would ask for the *ages* of the kids from all grades that do music.

And definitely each user.